# Pass a Listbox or Combobox as a control to a function?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, listbox

I'm trying to create a single function that I can call while filling either a `Listbox` OR a `Combobox`. Problem I'm running into is I get the error:

`"Items is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.ListControl"`.

Individually, in the code, `.items` *is* a member of each (both a `Listbox` or a `Combobox`).

Here's the current, broken function:

```
Public Function AutoAddWindowsViewers(ByVal ctlControl As ListControl)

    ' Auto-add Notepad to the list
    Dim strAutoAdd As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") & "\Notepad.exe"
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(strAutoAdd) = True AndAlso ctlControl.Items.Contains(strAutoAdd) = False Then ctlControl.Items.Add(strAutoAdd)

    ' Auto-add Wordpad to the list
    strAutoAdd = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.ProgramFiles & "\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(strAutoAdd) = True AndAlso ctlControl.Items.Contains(strAutoAdd) = False Then ctlControl.Items.Add(strAutoAdd)

End Function
```

I've also tried  replacing `ListControl` with the more generic `Control` in the parameter, but get the same error.

What did I miss?

**Update, Solution:**

With the help of @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå and @Tony Hopkinson this is what I ended up writing to make it work:

```
Public Sub AutoAddWindowsViewers(ByVal ctlControl As IList)

    ' Auto-add Notepad to the list
    Dim strAutoAdd As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") & "\Notepad.exe"
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(strAutoAdd) = True AndAlso ctlControl.Contains(strAutoAdd) = False Then ctlControl.Add(strAutoAdd)

    ' Auto-add Wordpad to the list
    strAutoAdd = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.ProgramFiles & "\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(strAutoAdd) = True AndAlso ctlControl.Contains(strAutoAdd) = False Then ctlControl.Add(strAutoAdd)

End Sub
```

And to call it I just pass the Control's `.items`:

i.e. `AutoAddWindowsViewers(cboComboBox1.items)`

Comment: Why aren't you just passing Items itself in?

Comment: Don't use `Listbox` or `Control`. Use `Object` instead and you are done. Also, you should use a `Sub` instead of a `Function` since you aren't returning any data.

Comment: Do as @TonyHopkinson says. Pass the object-collections as `IList`.

Comment: ...and turn on Option Strict

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo So your advice is to change the parameter to object, turn option strict off and use late bindings?

Comment: Of course the "best/proper" solution is to pass in the controls themselves but casting as object is a quick and dirty solution that works in this case.

Comment: Aha! IList, that did the trick, thanks. (Object doesn't/didn't  work btw, and I always have Strict On) =).

If you want to add that as a solution I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Someone -1'd the question? Really? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [Tony Hopkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968969), it would be better if you just change the parameter to `IList`. Then, whenever you call the function, pass the object collection (Items).

---

The function doesn't return anything so it should be a subroutine.

```
Public Sub AutoAddWindowsViewers(ByVal control As ListControl)

    If (control Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("control")
```

Create a variable to hold the list.

```
    Dim list As IList = Nothing
```

Check if the list control is bound to a data source. The [DataSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,77) property of a list control accepts two types of data: [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IListSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    If (Not control.DataSource Is Nothing) Then
        If (TypeOf control.DataSource Is IList) Then
            list = DirectCast(control.DataSource, IList)
        ElseIf (TypeOf control.DataSource Is IListSource) Then
            list = DirectCast(control.DataSource, IListSource).GetList()
        End If
    End If
```

If the list is still null, use the object collection.

```
    If (list Is Nothing) Then
        If (TypeOf control Is ListBox) Then
            list = DirectCast(control, ListBox).Items
        ElseIf (TypeOf control Is ComboBox) Then
            list = DirectCast(control, ComboBox).Items
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("...a descriptive error message...")
        End If
    End If
```

Note that an `ArgumentException` will be thrown if the list cannot hold string values .

```
    Dim item As String = Nothing

    'Auto-add Notepad to the list
    item = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") & "\Notepad.exe"
    If (FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(item) AndAlso (Not list.Contains(item))) Then list.Add(item)

    'Auto-add Wordpad to the list
    item = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.ProgramFiles & "\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
    If (FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(item) AndAlso (Not list.Contains(item))) Then list.Add(item)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The property Items is not included in Control or ListControl objects.

The code will work if you change the data type of the parameter `ctlControl` from ListControl to Object. However, this can leave the code open to errors in the future, so it's a good idea to check the data type of `ctlControl`:

```
If TypeOf (ctlControl) Is ListBox Or TypeOf (ctlControl) Is ComboBox Then
```